# Will using Apache's ProxyPass directive on persistent Ajax connections alleviate the connection limit error?

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd, proxypass

I've got some javascript that keeps a persistent Ajax connection open for each client, and I know that this can cause some serious issues for apache, but not for lighttpd.  One thing I learned from researching how to get around this was how to use the ProxyPass directive to send all requests for a certain directory to another address:port combination (without letting the user know).

What I want to know is, if I put my PHP in a proxy'd (to lighttpd) directory and call that with javascript, will this still count against my apache connection limit?  The reason I wonder is that apache is still serving the content, just not processing it.  Seems to me that this would be a connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a proxied connection counts against the connection limit.  However, it's certainly not going to consume as much in the way of resources as a connection where it has to serve anything; you could consider proxying the heavy PHP requests then increasing Apache's `MaxClients` setting (and other associated MPM settings if needed).

Comment: Thank you.  Just for reference, I have MaxClients set to 256, and when testing with 10 simultaneous persistent connections per browser window and using 2 browsers and reloading a few times each it seems that things are a tad slower and I have to reload twice to get a full page reload. Not exactly sure why this is, but for my application this should be good enough.